# Nested query with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three models: User, Post and Comment

```
var User = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String // obviously encrypted
});

var Post = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

var Comment = new Schema({
    text: String,
    post: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
    author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

**I need to get all posts in which the user has commented**.

I know it should be a very simple and common use case, but right now I can't figure a way to make the query without multiple calls and manually iterating the results.

I've been thinking of adding a `comments` field to the `Post` schema (which I'd prefer to avoid) and make something like:

```
Post.find()
    .populate({ path: 'comments', match: { author: user } })
    .exec(function (err, posts) {
        console.log(posts);
    });
```

Any clues without modifying my original schemas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have basically a couple of approaches to solving this.

1) **Without populating**. This uses promises with multiple calls. First query the `Comment` model for the particular user, then in the callback returned use the post ids in the comments to get the posts. You can use the **[promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-then)** like this:

```
var promise = Comment.find({ "author": userId }).select("post").exec();
promise.then(function (comments) {
    var postIds = comments.map(function (c) {
        return c.post;
    });
    return Post.find({ "_id": { "$in": postIds }).exec();
}).then(function (posts) {
    // do something with the posts here
    console.log(posts);

}).then(null, function (err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

2) **Using populate**. Query the `Comment` model for a particular user using the given userId,  select just the post field you want and populate it:

```
var query = Comment.find({ "author": userId });
query.select("post").populate("post");
query.exec(function(err, results){    
    console.log(results);
    var posts = results.map(function (r) { return r.post; });
    console.log(posts);
});
```

Comment: Looks promising (no pun intended), but it's exactly what I'm referring to in my post when I say I'm finding a way to avoid multiple calls (there are two `find`s) and iterating (map).

Comment: @javorosas Updated my answer with another approach which doesn't require multiple calls but manipulates the results array to return just the posts, closer to what you are looking for.